# Temperature sensor reads higher inside enclosure

Tags: sensor, temperature, enclosure

I have an HIH6130 temperature and humidity sensor inside a plastic enclosure with a Particle Photon.

When it takes reading while inside the enclosure, the readings are ~ 2 degrees too high, vs outside the enclosure.

Outside of putting a fan or a heat sink on it, any other ideas on how to reduce the heat buildup?

Comment: If you're putting a fan on it, you might as well just lose the enclosure.

Comment: put the heat source into another enclosure

Comment: I like the heat sync idea. It syncs the temperature around it with what it is trying to cool down.

Comment: Usually sensors are located at the bottom of a vented enclosure or protruding so that convection get external ambient flow and less influence from self heating. It ought to be the THT part and not SMT to locate the part in a better location or simply calibrate an offset

Comment: You could just implement a correction curve. A little experimentation should give you a pretty good idea of how far off the temperature will be.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz making the experiment fit the data or the data fit the experiment : called Finagle’s constant.. :) :)

Comment: @DavidSchwartz, the correction curve might work, but to a degree. The result, unfortunately, will depend on geometry of the enclosure, and its orientation with regard to the field of gravity. Which likely will be difficult to enforce in appliaction field.

Comment: NB It's "heat *sink*", not "heat sync" :)

Comment: If you're in a closed container, why do you think the humidity is going to change, so why do you need to measure it? Changing humidity implies connection to the outside, so why have an enclosure?

Comment: @WhatRoughBeast the sensor is inside an enclosed container but it's measuring the ambient temp & humidity outside the container.  There's a hole that the sensor is mounted against.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The ["Particle Photon" board](https://docs.particle.io/datasheets/photon-(wifi)/photon-datasheet/) (who makes these goofy names?) consumes 80 mA at 5V, making its power dissipation at 400 mW. This is a pretty substantial power consumption, and the heat must dissipate via build-up of temperature difference between the board and ambient air. If you want your sensor and MCU inside one enclosure, you should find a way to reduce the consumed power.

One way to reduce the power of a MCU is to use aggressive power management, to put the MCU into sleep mode as soon as you can afford, and not wake it up as long as you can. The time sampling for temperature and humidity is likely in several seconds (given thermal mass of typical PCB and enclosure), so there must be plenty of opportunities to exercise deep power saving modes.

Comment: Thanks, that makes a lot of sense.  I'll try the software solution first as the readings are taken once every 5 minutes, so that's plenty of power reduction.

Comment: @MishaM, good, just make sure to take data readings first while the board is at ambient, before running any radio communication stack.

Comment: Right, that makes sense.  I'm going to try to put the antenna on the outside and disable the chip antenna to see if that helps as well.